# Add missing elements to an array via function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of  hours/min,

```
$array = array("09:00","09:05","09:10","09:15","09:20","09:25","09:30","09:35","09:40","09:45","09:50","09:55","10:00","10:05","10:10","10:15","10:20","10:25","10:30","10:35","10:40","10:45","10:50","10:55",15:00","15:05","15:10","15:15","15:20","15:25","15:30","15:35","15:40","15:45","  15:50","15:55","16:00","16:05","16:10","16:15","16:20","16:25","16:30","16:35","16:40","16:45","16:50","16:55");
```

how can I add the missing hours?(from 11:00 to 14:55) the elements differ with 5 minutes from one-another.

Comment: Why "add the missing" hours? Does that buy you anything? Wouldn't it be simpler if you just generated the full array from scratch? Do you even need the result in an array, or are you just intending to process them one by one?

Comment: You can get the first and the last element and simply generate new array :).

Comment: Why bother to store them all in an array anyway if all the values are essentially numbers in a sequential order?  Given *N* time you will always be able to find the next **x** many values?

Comment: Why you treat the hours as string? It's much easier to do this with integers and just to combine them as you want to be shown properly.Think to try a loop for that,you definitely making a static string array while you want dynamic integer array.

Comment: @Jon 'add the missing hours' because i get an incomplete array (like the one above) from another script and i need to process a complete one.

Comment: @Mhche i treat hours as string because they are of type 'datetime' in the database.

Comment: You can convert your integer to string after you do that,also you can make a loop and define the numbers by the ASCII code so to be "strings"for your loop. But definitely you should start a new way to do that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should be:

```
$array = array("09:00",...);
```

Secondly, you could just generate the whole array. If you absolutely must do it like that then the easiest way would be to loop over the array you have and add missing items to new array, then merge them and sort resulting array.

Comment: that was just an example of how my array is, i wrote it quickly..sorry, anyway it's the hours that matter. I take an array of this kind from another script. it's incomplete. So i need to find and add the missing values. It should be done within a function. I'll try your solution.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assumed people would be rushing to answer - my comment stands, however you cut it storing all these times in an array seems like overkill but to answer the question... Not necessarily the simplest way, but the easiest for readability would be to make use of PHP's date functions:

```
for($i=strtotime('11:00'),$j=strtotime('15:00');$i<$j;$i+=5*60)
    $array[] = gmdate('H:i', $i);
$array = array_unique($array);
asort($array);

print_r($array);
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/irX05t)

Comment: You would gain a lot in performance if `strtotime('15:00')` would be outside the loop. If not it will be evaluated about 50 times and it's not the lightest of functions. Overall performance wouldn't change a lot, but still.

Comment: @Nux thx, I wrote it quickly :P but technically ye so I've updated the post.  Given the context though the difference is negligible.